# Delphi RIO changes old _TLB.pas parameters datatype definitions

Tags: delphi, typelib

The COM dll was developed in Delphi 2009. We successfully upgraded the project in Delphi RIO. Tested fine as well.

Now when I add a new method in DLL interface, and regenerate _TLB.pas in type library editor, it not only adds the new method, but also changes the datatype of few parameters of unchanged procedures/functions.

Delphi 2009 Definition:

```
procedure SaveData(var AParam1: OleVariant;......); //custom unchanged method
// Methods from IAppServer
function AS_ApplyUpdates(const ProviderName: WideString; Delta: OleVariant; MaxErrors: Integer; 
                         out ErrorCount: Integer; var OwnerData: OleVariant): OleVariant; dispid 20000000;
function AS_GetRecords(const ProviderName: WideString; Count: Integer; out RecsOut: Integer; 
                       Options: Integer; const CommandText: WideString; var Params: OleVariant; 
                       var OwnerData: OleVariant): OleVariant; dispid 20000001;
function AS_RowRequest(const ProviderName: WideString; Row: OleVariant; RequestType: Integer; ...
```

Delphi RIO definitions:

```
procedure SaveData(**const** AParam1: OleVariant;......); //custom unchanged method
// Methods from IAppServer
function AS_ApplyUpdates(const ProviderName: WideString; Delta: OleVariant; MaxErrors: **SYSINT**; 
                         out ErrorCount: **SYSINT**; var OwnerData: OleVariant): OleVariant; dispid 20000000;
function AS_GetRecords(const ProviderName: WideString; Count: **SYSINT**; out RecsOut: **SYSINT**; 
                       Options: **SYSINT**; const CommandText: WideString; var Params: OleVariant; 
                       var OwnerData: OleVariant): OleVariant; dispid 20000001;
function AS_RowRequest(const ProviderName: WideString; Row: OleVariant; RequestType: **SYSINT**; ...
```

Changes are in enclosed with **.. (For SaveData(), 'var' to 'const' and for others 'integer' to 'SYSINT').

Another important detail is, in D2009, in the type library editor, the SaveData >> AParam1 is defined of datatype "POleVariant1", and "POleVariant1" is an alias of type "^OleVariant".

The question is: should I keep the type library definitions of the unchanged methods as it is and let _TLB.pas get updated as above?

Comment: `integer` and `sysint` seems the same, but `var AParam1` and `const AParam1` are not the same. It may be a bug/regression in Delphi 10.4. You could continue to use the D2009 import, anyway, even on Delphi 10.4. Use the _tlb.pas which works....

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez - Thank your for your input.